# jQuery hover falling off from the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code at the moment.
I need to prevent hover box 'falling down' on the bottom of the page while hovering on paragraphs. I managed to prevent that on the right on smaller screens but i cant on bottom.

```js
$(function() {
  var moveLeft = 20;
  var moveDown = 10;
  // var moveRight = 10;

  $('.hoverKartX').hover(function(e) {
    $('.hoverKart').show();
    
  }, function() {
    $('.hoverKart').hide();
  });

  $('.hoverKartX').mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.hoverKart').css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    
    // preventing 'falling out to the right' on smaller screens
    if ($('.hoverKart').position()['left'] + $('.hoverKart').width() > $(window).width()) {
        $('.hoverKart').css("left", $(window).width() - $(".hoverKart").width());
    };
});

});
```

```css
.hoverKart {
  position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 220px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hoverKart"> <!-- hidden -->
  <p>
  TEST
  </p>
</div>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
```

Comment: Given that the "hover" is larger than the screen in the snippet, can you explain what you expect to happen?  If it doesn't go off the bottom then it will instead go off the top!

Comment: I edited my snippet, try it in a full screen mode. I need to prevent the box 'falling down' on the bottom of the screen, just like on the right. But the same logic like i did for the 'falling out" to the right its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `e` object from `$('.hoverKartX').mousemove(function(e) {` to calculate how far from the width of the window the mouse is. If distance is less than the height of your `.hoverKart`, then you can adjust its offset with the edge to make it stay within the window.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the logic for off the right (left / width) so apply the same login to the bottom (pageY+height):

```
if ((e.pageY + moveDown + $(".hoverKart").height()) 
    > ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())) {
  $('.hoverKart').css("top", 
       $(window).height() - $(".hoverKart").height() + $(window).scrollTop()
  );
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  var moveLeft = 20;
  var moveDown = 10;
  // var moveRight = 10;

  $('.hoverKartX').hover(function(e) {
    $('.hoverKart').show();
    
  }, function() {
    $('.hoverKart').hide();
  });

  $('.hoverKartX').mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.hoverKart').css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    $(".hoverKart>p").html($(this).html())
    
    // preventing 'falling out to the right' on smaller screens
    if ($('.hoverKart').position().left + $('.hoverKart').width() > $(window).width()) {
        $('.hoverKart').css("left", $(window).width() - $(".hoverKart").width() - moveLeft);
    };
    
    if ((e.pageY + moveDown + $(".hoverKart").height()) > ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())) {
      $('.hoverKart').css("top", $(window).height() - $(".hoverKart").height() + $(window).scrollTop());
    }
});

});
```

```css
.hoverKart {
  position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
}
p.hoverKartX {
  border:1px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hoverKart"> <!-- hidden -->
  <p>
  TEST
  </p>
</div>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test1
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test2
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test3
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test4
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test5
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test6
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test7
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test8
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test9
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testa
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testb
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testc
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testd
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
teste
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testf
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testg
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testh
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testi
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testj
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testk
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testl
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
testm
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

```js
$(function() {
  var moveLeft = 20;
  var moveDown = 10;
  // var moveRight = 10;

  $('.hoverKartX').hover(function(e) {
    $('.hoverKart').show();
    
  }, function() {
    $('.hoverKart').hide();
  });

  $('.hoverKartX').mousemove(function(e) {
    var offset = $( this ).offset().top,
    bodyOffset=$(document).scrollTop();
    if($( this ).offset().top+$(".hoverKart").height()+moveDown<bodyOffset+$(window).height()){
      $('.hoverKart').css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    }
    else{
      $('.hoverKart').css('top', bodyOffset+$(window).height()-$(".hoverKart").height())
      .css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    }
    
    // preventing 'falling out to the right' on smaller screens
    if ($('.hoverKart').position()['left'] + $('.hoverKart').width() > $(window).width()) {
        $('.hoverKart').css("left", $(window).width() - $(".hoverKart").width());
    };
});

});
```

```css
.hoverKart {
  position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 220px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hoverKart"> <!-- hidden -->
  <p>
  TEST
  </p>
</div>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
<p class="hoverKartX">
test
</p>
```

Comment: Where did `+220+` come from?  Don't hardcode "magic numbers" - what if the css is changed?

Comment: just for demonstration can be replace with `$(".hoverKart").height()`